# How can I set in my profile, to see only tags that I chose?

Tags: support, tags

For example I want to set some tags in my profile (dota-2, world-of-warcraft, skyrim) so I can only see questions with these tags when I enter the website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First way:

1. Go to http://stackexchange.com/filters
2. For (one-of-your-tags in your-tags)
   {

   1. Fill "Just questions tagged with the ... tag" with one-of-your-tags
   2. Fill "Just these sites" with "arqade"
   3. Hit "add rule"

   }
3. Fill "What should this filter be named?" with any name you want
4. Click "Save Changes"

## Second way:

Simply bookmark this address:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota-2+or+world-of-warcraft+or+skyrim

Comment: I see what you did there. Here, let me do the same thing: while (true) { arqade.meta.reply("lol +1"); }